# ValueError while doing merge with DataFrames using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge three DataFrames using Pandas. Why do I get this error message?

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

This is the code:

```
df=pd.merge(energy,GDP,ScimEn,on="Country")
```

Here `energy`,`GDP`,`ScimEn` are the three DataFrames I was trying to merge.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can take a look at the documentation of [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). You can merge exactly two data frames using pd.merge

Answer (score 5):

The call signature of [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) accepts only 2 DataFrames to merge;

```
pd.merge(left, right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False, sort=False, suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False, validate=None)
```

So you'd need to do it in 2 steps:

```
df = pd.merge(energy, GDP, on="Country")
df = pd.merge(df, ScimEn, on="Country")
```

Or chain the 2 steps together with [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) which allows for the immediate use of the new DataFrame:

```
df = energy.merge(GDP, on="Country").merge(ScimEn, on="Country")
```

Also it's a good idea to set the `how` keyword explicitly. If there are countries that are in one of the DataFrames but not in the others, then merging using the default `how=inner` would result in lost data, and should be changed to `outer` if you want to keep all data from all DataFrames.